# SQLite in Android: Foreign Keys and <table constraint> expected

Tags: java, android, mysql, sqlite

I have had a search about to try to understand the nature of this problem, but have not had any luck as of yet.

I'm making a RPG-style to-do list to teach myself Android/Java, and I'm making two tables: categories (strength, intelligence etc) and Quests: name, description, EXP etc.

I want each quest to have a category, but I'm getting a table constraints error. My code is below, and the GitHub link is [here](https://github.com/ShetlandJ/ToDoList/blob/master/app/src/main/java/myfirstgame/todolist/DBHelper.java).

```
public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db){
    setForeignKeyConstraintsEnabled(db);

db.execSQL("CREATE TABLE " + CATEGORY_TABLE_NAME + "(id INTEGER primary key autoincrement NOT NULL, name TEXT, exp INTEGER, level INTEGER )");
db.execSQL("CREATE TABLE " + QUEST_TABLE_NAME + "(id INTEGER primary key autoincrement NOT NULL, name TEXT, description TEXT, expValue INTEGER, category INTEGER NOT NULL, FOREIGN KEY (category) REFERENCES categories (id), date TEXT");

db.execSQL("INSERT INTO " + CATEGORY_TABLE_NAME + "('name', 'exp', 'level') VALUES ('Strength', 0, 0 );");
db.execSQL("INSERT INTO " + CATEGORY_TABLE_NAME + "('name', 'exp', 'level') VALUES ('Stamina', 0, 0 );");
db.execSQL("INSERT INTO " + CATEGORY_TABLE_NAME + "('name', 'exp', 'level') VALUES ('Intelligence', 0, 0 );");
db.execSQL("INSERT INTO " + CATEGORY_TABLE_NAME + "('name', 'exp', 'level') VALUES ('Social', 0, 0 );");
db.execSQL("INSERT INTO " + QUEST_TABLE_NAME + "('name', 'description', 'expValue', 'category', 'date') VALUES ('Gym', 'Weightlifting down The Gym', '300', '1', '25/05/2017');");
}
```

The error is coming at 'date TEXT', and the error says:

```
<table constraint> expected, got 'date'.
```

What's the problem here?

Comment: try put it (date Text) before Foreign key i'm not sure but i think you need to put all colums before foreign key

Comment: @crammeur If I move date before the FOREIGN KEY bit, I get the following error:

')', DEFERRABLE, MATCH, NOT, ON or comma expected, unexpected end of file

Comment: so change date to date1 because date is function

Comment: Original position or new position and changed to date1 still doesn't make a difference

Comment: your forgot ) at the end of the string

Comment: I got it working with your suggestions! I used:

        db.execSQL("CREATE TABLE " + QUEST_TABLE_NAME + "(id INTEGER primary key autoincrement NOT NULL, name TEXT, description TEXT, expValue INTEGER, date TEXT, category INTEGER NOT NULL, FOREIGN KEY (category) REFERENCES '+CATEGORY_TABLE_NAME+' (id))");

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/158732/discussion-between-crammeur-and-james-stewart).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your issue is that you have mixed up **column_constraint** syntax with **table_constraint** syntax (***i.e coded the latter where the former should be used***).

You could fix the issue by using

**`db.execSQL("CREATE TABLE " + QUEST_TABLE_NAME + "(id INTEGER primary key autoincrement NOT NULL, name TEXT, description TEXT, expValue INTEGER, category INTEGER NOT NULL REFERENCES categories (id), date TEXT");`**

As is explained below as is the alternative syntax.

That is the column constraint syntax starts with the **`REFERENCES ....`** and is part of the column definition (i.e. the column name is implicit), whilst table_constraint syntax starts with **`FORIEGN KEY(column_name) REFERENCES ...` and follows the column definitions**

So you could have either :-

**Column_constraint syntax**

- As part of a column definition
- `category INTEGER NOT NULL REFERENCES categories (id)`

e.g.

```
CREATE TABLE yourtablename (id INTEGER primary key autoincrement NOT NULL, name TEXT, description TEXT, expValue INTEGER, category INTEGER NOT NULL REFERENCES categories (id), date TEXT)
```

or

**Table_constraint syntax**

- after the column's have been defined, but still within the column definition i.e. still inside the brackets.
- `FOREIGN KEY (category) REFERENCES categories (id)`

e.g

```
CREATE TABLE yourtablename (id INTEGER primary key autoincrement NOT NULL, name TEXT, description TEXT, expValue INTEGER, category INTEGER NOT NULL, date TEXT, FOREIGN KEY (category) REFERENCES categories (id));
```

You may find [column-constraint](https://www.sqlite.org/syntax/column-constraint.html) and [table-constraint](https://www.sqlite.org/syntax/table-constraint.html) of use.

---

**date** can be a column name. However, I'd suggest that it is wise to not use any SQLite keyword, such as date, as a column name.